# How to get my text logo to move left of my navbar links

Tags: html, css

I have made my navbar and positioned it where I need it. I then have tried to add in a text logo and wanted it be moved to the left. I have wrapped a span tag in a div ID and have tried multiple things, from floats to lefts, to rights, to flex boxes and it wont budge. I can change the font size but I cant seem to do anything else with it.

```css
.center {
  margin: auto 90px;
  width: 1180px;
  height: 485px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2em;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
  float: right;
  font-size: 17px;
  left: 190px;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: white;
  right: 190px;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.4em;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: black;
}

.menu li a {
  color: white;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  background: #1bc2a2;
  color: white;
}

li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

li:hover li {
  float: none;
  z-index: 999;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.menu li:hover a,
.main-navigation li:hover a {
  background: #1bc2a2;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
}

li:hover li a:hover {
  background: #246133;
}

.main-navigation li ul li {
  border-top: 0;
}

div#logo {
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: none;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-navigation">
  <li>
    <div id="logo">
      <span>GETUWIRED</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">OUR STORY</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">OUR COMMITMENT TO YOU</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">LOCATIONS</a>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">AUSTIN, TX</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">ATLANTA, GA</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">SEATTLE, WA</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">PORTLAND, OR</a>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">NEW ARRIVALS</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">FEATURED</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">TOP RATED</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">HIS</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">HERS</a>
          <li>
            <a href="#">KIDS</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">SPRING CATALOG</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">THE ESSENTIALS</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">SALE</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">BLOG</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've edit some code from you and I got result hopefully it seems like you need. The reason why your text logo can't be positioning or move to left, It's because of your main-navigation width, not 100%. I modify some code of you here.

```css
.center{
      margin: auto 90px;
      width: 1180px;
      height: 485px;
      position: relative;
      line-height: 2em;
      }

      ul {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      color: black;
      float: right;
      font-size: 17px;
      /* left: 190px; */
      }

      ul li {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      background: white;
      /* right: 190px; */
      }

      li ul {
      display: none;
      }

      ul li a {
      display: block;
      padding: 0.4em;
      text-decoration: none;
      white-space: nowrap;
      color: black;

      }

      .menu li a {
      color: white;
      }

      .menu li a:hover {
      background: #1bc2a2;
      color: white;
      }

      li:hover > ul {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;

      }

      li:hover li {
      float: none;
      z-index: 999;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 14px;

      }

      .menu li:hover a,
      
      /* Add This */
      .main-navigation {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .main-navigation li:hover a {
      background: #1bc2a2;
      border-radius: 1.3px;

      }

      li:hover li a:hover {
      background: #246133;
      }

      .main-navigation li ul li {
      border-top: 0;
      }

      div#logo{
       font-size: 23px;
       font-weight: bold;
       float: none;
       text-align: left;

      }
```

```html
<ul class="main-navigation">
    <li>
        <div id="logo">
            <span>GETUWIRED</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    
    <!-- Add This -->
    <div style="float:right">
      <li>
        <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">OUR STORY</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">OUR COMMITMENT TO YOU</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">LOCATIONS</a>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">AUSTIN, TX</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">ATLANTA, GA</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">SEATTLE, WA</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">PORTLAND, OR</a>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">NEW ARRIVALS</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">FEATURED</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">TOP RATED</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">HIS</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">HERS</a>
              <li>
                <a href="#">KIDS</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">SPRING CATALOG</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">THE ESSENTIALS</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">SALE</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">BLOG</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```